# SQL / Wordpress - query for removing a comment field

Tags: mysql, sql, string, wordpress, sql-update

Does anyone know how can I replace the "comment_author_url" field from all comments by running a SQL query?

for example if this field is `http://google.com` to replace it with `""` (empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET comment_author_url = ''
 WHERE comment_author_url = 'http://google.com'
```

Comment: Nice answer. Quick and simple. Would make for a neato plugin with some regex matching. ;-)

Comment: @hsatterwhite: Swap `WHERE comment_author_url = ...` with `WHERE comment_author_url REGEXP ...` - there's [more info on MySQL's regex support in this documentation link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).